# Sphinx-doc: Search tool not returning expected results?

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx-doc is great in helping us generate HTML pages for our Python libraries and make the documentation searchable!  However, the search tool is not returning results that I expect...

For example:

```
def foo():
   """
   show ip address
   """
   pass
```

If I search for just "show" or "address" using the html search box, it matched the `foo()` function (which is expected).  If I search for "ip", no match.  If I search all three words, no match.  I noticed that "ip" is not in the searchindex.js and it appeared that words less than or equal to 3 characters are not indexed.  This is a problem since anyone using a search string that contains a word that is less than or equal to 3 characters will not get the expected result (this is worse than just ignoring those words during search).

Is there any way around it?  Is this a bug?

Comment: I think the three letter limitation is default setting for many search engines, not only one embedded in Sphinx. For example MySQL suffer from the same issue.

Comment: If two characters are not being indexed, the search should ignore the two character terms so the result would not fail 100%.  I wonder how that is done for other search engines...

Comment: Smells like a bug. Maybe land this on Sphinx issue tracker?